# How to use FINDSTR on files only a week old?

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I often have to search log files on servers with hardly anything installed. I can use `findstr` to find something in the logs, but sometimes there are like two years of log files on those machines, so I want to look into the recent log files only. Is there a handy way to do that? What I have come up with myself is perhaps not the most elegant and efficient way to do it.

```
md newer
forfiles /d 07-07-2022 /c "cmd /c copy @file .\newer"
findstr /D:newer /I /C:"could not find" *.log > .\newer\tmp.txt
notepad .\newer\tmp.txt
```

And then with the help of Mofi I could improve it to this. But I would also like to search maybe in the subdirectory of some folder:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set source="c:\logfiles"
set searchstring="test"
set daysback="30"

 for /F "tokens=1-3*" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe %source% %SystemDrive%\NotExistingFolder *.log /MAXAGE:%daysback% /L /NDL /NJH /NJS') do (
     @if "%%G%%H" == "NewFile" %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /C:"test" "%%J")>"FindResults.txt" 
     if exist "FindResults.txt" for %%I in ("FindResults.txt") do if %%~zI == 0 (del "FindResults.txt") else start "" %SystemRoot%\notepad.exe "FindResults.txt"
  )


endlocal
```

Comment: Well, I use licensed shareware file manager Total Commander which has lots of very easy to use options for files search. In Total Commander can be navigated to the directory containing the log files, pressed Alt+F7 to open the files search dialog window, enabled the option to search for a text and select on second tab the option to search only in files not older than 1 week (or x minutes, hours, days, weeks, months, years). There can be a lot of time saved on using the right tool. But yes, it is possible to write a script for this task whereby I would suggest a PowerShell script for this task.

Comment: There can be used in a batch file with first line `@echo off` and second line `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` as third command line `(for /F "tokens=1-3*" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe . %SystemDrive%\NotExistingFolder *.log /MAXAGE:7 /L /NDL /NJH /NJS') do @if "%%G%%H" == "NewFile" %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /C:"could not find" "%%J")>"FindResults.txt"` and next `if exist "FindResults.txt" for %%I in ("FindResults.txt") do if %%~zI == 0 (del "FindResults.txt") else start "" %SystemRoot%\notepad.exe "FindResults.txt"` and `endlocal` as last line.

Comment: Thank you Mofi. I got it working. I first made a stupid mistake, thinking 'and next' was part of the statement. Not an indication I had to put the next piece of code on the next line.